# Run workflow several times to load data from source to single target

Tags: mapping, workflow, etl

I am having a relational source having 60 records in it.
I want to run a workflow for this mapping, for the first time it should load only 20(1-20) records , 2nd time remaining 20(21-30) records, 3rd time remaining 20(31-60) records to a single source.
how can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to:

- use a mapping variable eg. $$rowAmount with initial value of 20
- add a `Sequence` to generate row numbers
- use a `Filter` with a condition `RowId>$$rowAmount-20 AND RowId<$$rowAmount`
- use `SETVARIABLE` function to increase $$rowAmount by 20 and store in repository